# Ubuntu 22.04 without built-in display

Tags: display, 22.04, hdmi, wayland

I have a ThinkPad X230 with Ubuntu 22.04 and Kernel 5.15.0-46-generic. I want to transform this laptop in a small desktop computer. This means I'll remove the built-in keyboard and monitor. The built-in monitor will be replaced by a HDMI monitor. My setup works when both monitors are connected, i.e the second monitor is recognized and works perfectly. I used it in "single display" mode from the Ubuntu settings.

When I disconnect the built-in monitor, the laptop boots and I can see the boot screen stuff on my second monitor (configured accordingly in BIOS). However once in Ubuntu I see only the wallpaper as if I was screen sharing with another inexistent monitor. How can I set up Ubuntu such that the external monitor is used by Wayland/Gnome even if the built-in display isn’t connected?

Here some information. I used `gnome-randr` to try to correct the problem (a utility found here https://github.com/maxwellainatchi/gnome-randr-rust)

```
gnome-randr
supports-mirroring: true
layout-mode: physical
supports-changing-layout-mode: false
global-scale-required: false
renderer: "native"
legacy-ui-scaling-factor: 2

logical monitor 0:
x: 0, y: 0, scale: 2, rotation: normal, primary: yes
associated physical monitors:
    HDMI-1 ONX Mira133 202105

HDMI-1 ONX Mira133 202105
  2200x1650@38.002471923828125  2200x1650   38.00*+     [x1.00+, x2.00, x3.00]
   1920x1080@37.97979736328125  1920x1080   37.98       [x1.00+, x2.00]
 1600x1200i@37.997997283935547  1600x1200   38.00       [x1.00+, x2.00]
   1280x960@38.033977508544922  1280x960    38.03       [x1.00+]
     1024x768@38.0223388671875  1024x768    38.02       [x1.00+]
display-name: "SOMELEC Z.I. Du Vert Galanta 13.3\""
is-builtin: false

LVDS-1 LGD 0x02d8 0x00000000
   1366x768@60.018642425537109  1366x768    60.02+      [x1.00+]
   1280x720@59.855125427246094  1280x720    59.86       [x1.00+]
   1024x768@59.920131683349609  1024x768    59.92       [x1.00+]
    800x600@59.861404418945312  800x600     59.86       [x1.00+]
is-builtin: true
display-name: "Built-in display"
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: it works when I start the laptop with both screens and then remove the built-in one. Then Ubuntu “keeps” the correct settings and I could have access there to the terminal with only one screen plugged and actually see what I’m writing... can I set it up from there ?

EDIT2: Here's my monitors.xml file

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>2</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1</connector>
          <vendor>ONX</vendor>
          <product>Mira133</product>
          <serial>202105</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2200</width>
          <height>1650</height>
          <rate>38.002471923828125</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <disabled>
      <monitorspec>
        <connector>LVDS-1</connector>
        <vendor>LGD</vendor>
        <product>0x02d8</product>
        <serial>0x00000000</serial>
      </monitorspec>
    </disabled>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only the second monitor connected, I manage to navigate through the settings menu with the keyboard (without actually seeing what I was doing) and to set the second monitor as Single-Display in Settings > Display. A new configuration showed up in my monitors.xml file:

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>2</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1</connector>
          <vendor>ONX</vendor>
          <product>Mira133</product>
          <serial>202105</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2200</width>
          <height>1650</height>
          <rate>38.002471923828125</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <disabled>
      <monitorspec>
        <connector>LVDS-1</connector>
        <vendor>unknown</vendor>
        <product>unknown</product>
        <serial>unknown</serial>
      </monitorspec>
    </disabled>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

As one can see, the difference lies in the "unknown" value of the tags `vendor`, `product` and `serial`. I guess this means Ubuntu recognizes my setup as a two-screens setup and one monitor is "unknown" (because not plugged in). Perhaps this might help other people wanting to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the monitors configuration file.

`gedit ~/.config/monitors.xml`

Find the display you wish to make primary, and change to

`<primary>yes</primary>`

And make sure to change the other monitor to

`<primary>no</primary>`

Now save the file, make it non-writable, and reboot.

---

Using the display configuration of xfce4 saves the settings permanently, it even automatically figures out that you can't see the laptop screen, and adjusts back during login.

So this is a solution but an xfce4 one, not gnome's.

You need to be handy with the terminal, in case xfce4 loses configuration, just to keep that in mind.

Comment: I guess Gnome does also recognize changes in monitor setups automatically, and saves settings, but it seems to be different for the built-in one. For example, I can plug-in/plug-out the external monitor and it changes everything automatically, but when I plug-out the built-in screen, it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @UnderTheHoud answer update !

Comment: Thanks. As you can see in my Edit2, my monitors.xml file does contain the primary tag on the right place. Could it be a problem with the “logical monitor” tag? It seems like the built-in is not a logical monitor and is perhaps “required”... I don’t know I’m just guessing

Comment: @UnderTheHoud if you can write in BASH, make a script on desktop that makes that xml config you posted down below, everytime you boot, and keep it there.

Comment: Thanks but there is no need of rewriting the file every time the computer boots, since it is not going to be overwritten. I mean the file just stays as it is.

Comment: @UnderTheHoud good for you then ;), congratulations !